# Convert a string with escape sequences to their original character representation in python

Tags: python

Let's assume I have a program that receives inputs that I can't really control.  The following variables are fed in as is (we can't change the inputs here):

```
a = "C:\temp"
b = "C:\games"
c = "Hello World"
d = "\t"
```

Unfortunately, Python will misinterpret things and put in escape sequences:

```
In [138]: a[2]
Out[138]: '\t'

In [139]: b[2]
Out[139]: '\\'

In [140]: d[0]
Out[140]: '\t'
```

Let's assume the answer has already been found.  It should do the following:

```
def answer(x):
    pass #TODO: your code goes here
```

Desired outputs:

```
In [200]: answer(a)[2]
Out [201]: '\\'

In [202]: answer(a)[3]
Out [203]: 't'

In [204]: answer(b)[2]
Out [205]: '\\'

In [206]: answer(b)[3]
Out [207]: 'g'

In [208]: answer(c)
Out [209]: 'Hello World'
```

I've already tried using the ast module and also using decode, to no avail:

```
In [144]: import ast

In [145]: ast.literal_eval(a)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    C:  emp
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Or with decode:

```
In [147]: a.decode('string-escape')[2]
Out[147]: '\t'
```

Solve for answer()

Edit: "\", not "\" in the [204] example

Comment: `'\'` can not be achieved since `'\'` is always an escape prefix, I believe you are looking for `'\\'`.

Comment: Show us how you're taking this input. Most reasonable ways of taking input will not apply escape sequence interpretation in the first place.

Comment: `b[2]`, at least, *is* a single backslash. You are confusing the return value of the indexing with the string representation of the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `encode` not `decode`:

```
>>> "\t".encode('string-escape')
'\\t'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert this strings into their representation using `repr`, then strip `'` and `"` and take the char:

```
>>> a = 'C:\temp'
>>> a[2]
'\t'
>>> repr(a).strip('\'"')[2]
'\\'
```

---

`answer` for that matter, would look like

```
def answer(x): return repr(x).strip('\'"')
```

Comment: This will produce incorrect output for strings that start or end with quotes, such as `"foo"`: `answer('"foo"')` -> `foo` instead of `"foo"`. You could just do `repr(a)[1:-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, you should convert your string into their original representation using `repr` then use `str.partition()` like this example:

```
>>> a = 'C:\temp'
>>> repr(a).partition('\\')

("'C:", '\\', "temp'")
```